# Local Account ( with LAPS) vs Domain Joined Account ( member of local Administrator group )

Tags: administration

I got a question.

What would be preferred more secure option for managing computers.

Using local admin accounts with LAPS, password changed every 24hrs

Or Domain Joined account that is member of local Administrator group on each computer.

The tasks that would performed is deployment of software remotely.

Thx

Comment: What software/method are you using for deployment?

Comment: Psexec or PDQ..

Comment: Using local accounts (different password per computer) would be more secure but likely difficult with psexec or PDQ. I would recommend a domain account added to local admin, and restrict the account (via GPO) from interactive logins.